# Why is my heading and text not appearing?

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is really simple, sorry but I'm a web noob. I can't get the headings to show up on the page.

```
<html>

<style>

body {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #bdc3c7, #2c3e50);
}

<style/>

<body>

<h1>That Was Then<h1/>
<p> A toronto based band <p>

<body/>

<html/>
```

Comment: Learn basic html syntax? closing tags are `</foo>`, not `<foo/>` the trailing `/` is a self-closing tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The syntax for an end tag is `</type>` not `<type/>`.

This would have been picked up if you had [used a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Comment: thank you, I will use that in the future